# Emacs on ubuntu 12.04 - cannot get C-<UP> to display shell history (imitate M-p)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, emacs, key-bindings

I am running emacs on ubuntu 12.04. I can't find a way to get to the previous command in the shell mode easily. On other platforms I used to do `C-<UP>` for this. [Gnu emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Ring.html#Shell-Ring) link implies this should be valid but it is not. `M-p` works for me though. I probably need to rebind  `M-p` but don't know how. Most info tells how to bind a key to a particular routine but not to another key. I appreciate any input on this.Thanks

Comment: If you use `M-x terminal` instead of `M-x shell` your shell's key bindings will take effect when you are in the terminal window. Of course the downside is that normal emacs keybindings are _not_ in effect.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that. Unfortunately, it still does not work

Comment: A plain up arrow should work!

Comment: I have just tested it with `emacs 24.3.1` on ubuntu 13.04. There, `C-↑` works as expected.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 12.04 and emacs 23.3.1. I will see if I can upgrade. Thanks for the info. In any case, a side query is can I not explicitly remap M-p to C-<UP> i.e. can I not make one key combo bind to anotehr existing key combo? I searched but could not find an answer.

Comment: Is your desktop binding `C-<UP>` to something, preventing Emacs from seeing the keypress?

Comment: To find whether the desktop binds `<C-up>` try `C-h k <C-up>` in shell-mode. This should open a help buffer with a description of the key binding.

Comment: apparently C-h in emacs is not working as expected In shell mode it goes back by a character. When I am editing a text file, it goes to the beginning of the buffer. I don't have any fancy customization. I am running emacs on ubuntu via Xshell on Windows xp. It may be there is probably an issue in the local environment. I guess I will have to check on my own. Thanks for the responses.